# How to restore a removed ui.item?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

My element styling depends on the element order. Since jQuery UI keeps the original item while dragging a helper hidden, the hidden element breaks the styling. I can remove the `ui.item` upon starting the drag event. Though, how can I restore the element after it was removed?

http://jsfiddle.net/MnSRd/8/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul { height: 50px; }
li { float: left; width: 50px; height: inherit; background: #ccc; margin: 0 10px 0 0; }
li.placeholder { background: #f00; }
li:nth-child(1):before { content: '1'; }
li:nth-child(2):before { content: '2'; }
li:nth-child(3):before { content: '3'; }
li:nth-child(4):before { content: '4'; }
li:nth-child(5):before { content: '5'; }
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('ul').sortable({
    helper: 'clone',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    start: function (e, ui) {
        console.log(ui.item.remove()); // temporary remove
    },
    beforeStop: function (e, ui) {
        // how to bring the item back?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first `hide()` the item and then `show()` it again. `remove()` completely removes it from the DOM so you cannot restore it unless you `clone()` it and then you attach it back or simply use jQuery [`detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) [Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MnSRd/10/)

```
$('ul').sortable({
    helper: 'clone',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    start: function (e, ui) {
        ui.item.hide(); // temporary remove
    },
    beforeStop: function (e, ui) {
        ui.item.show();
    }
});
```

After reading the comments I believe that what you want from the sortable is to use `helper: 'original'` which is the default helper instead of `helper: 'clone'`.

Comment: You have misread the question. To begin with, jQuery UI already hides the element for you, so implicitly setting `ui.item.hide()` is redundant. Furthermore, simply hiding the element does not solve the issue that I've described.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas I have also answered that if you explicitly want to remove the element then you can clone it and attach it back when the necessary action completes.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, though the problem with cloning the element and the putting it back is that reference to the original element is lost, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/MnSRd/12/

Comment: @GajusKuizinas You are not wrong the element is cloned and then the original one is removed. In your example the element is being attached after all the other elements in the list because the element parent is the UL and you're appending to it. What exactly is the desired behavior?

Comment: My answer solves the orignal problem. You have so far not provided a solution for removing an element and then restoring the element maintaining the original reference (ie. not breaking the sortable behaviour). The show/hide approach is nothing but redundant.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas You can user detach() to keep the reference: http://api.jquery.com/detach/

Comment: Detaching element sounds like a good idea. Though, appending the detached element nevertheless seem to break the sorting behaviour. http://jsfiddle.net/MnSRd/13/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23447/discussion-between-konstantin-d-infragistics-and-gajus-kuizinas)

Answer (score 0):

While this might not be an answer to everyone, it will likely solve any similar issues.

```
$('ul').sortable({
    helper: 'clone',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    start: function (e, ui) {
        ui.item.appendTo(ui.item.parent());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MnSRd/11/

Instead of removing the UI element, I am appending it to the end of the parent container. Thus it does not have any effect on the element styling.